# Can't set marks in VIM (apostrophe is set as a mark)

Tags: vim

I am having a problem setting marks in vim. For starters, I have a US International Keyboard, so I use <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to write "á". This means that In vim, to access to the mark "a" I have to write <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, and I am fine with that. Except that it doesn't work. Even if I use another letter, for example "b", the cursor jumps anywhere but to my mark (it doesn't mather if I use <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd>.

When I see the marks with the command `:marks`, the `'` (apostrophe) is usually set as a mark to some random (or at least I can't find a pattern), line in the buffer. And I can't seem to delete that mark.

Does anyone have some information regarding this?

Thanks!

Comment: The `'` mark marks the location before the last jump. It is set automatically. According to `help :keepjumps` you can turn of setting the `'` mark. But I do not think that will help you with your problem. I am not able to reproduce your problem with an international keyboard.

Comment: Weird. Maybe is because I am using macvim? (I am on osx).

Comment: So, it seems to be a Macvim problem, when I use terminal vim it works ok. That's weird.

Comment: It ended up being a Macvim related problem. I fixed it going to Preferences->Advanced and unchecking "Draw marked text inline".

Comment: @crscardellino check "eurkey" layout which allows you to type `'` like normal on US keyboards *and* produce characters like `á` or `à` easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you are trying to write special characters you make 
two vim commands collides.
Since your character are defined by marks:
'a  jump to line of mark a (first non-blank character in line)
`a  jump to position (line and column) of mark a

What you can do is use [diagraphs](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters) of vim to write such characters and
only use ' or ` for marks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying. I don't want to use special characters as mark. I want to use the regular a-z marks, but I can't, since for some reason my apostrophe is set to some random mark.

Comment: It is weird that you have to type `' + space + a` to go to mark a. Usually you don't need a space in between

Comment: I did try `:delm '` and it doesn't work. It says E475, invalid argument. And regarding using space, that's because I configure the english keyboard to have the `'` key to work as an accent (I'm Spanish speaker so I use them a lot), that is the configuration known as US International Keyboard.

Comment: I am a french speaker and I use a us keyboard too. But I didn't configure the accent I use diagraphs instead. What you can do is have a look at it and if it suits go back to the default english keyboard setting.

Comment: Yeah, I really wish there was another way. Because It's easier for me this way, I don't use only vim, and the US international configuration is useful for me in all the other apps. Besides I understand this should be possible, or at least I have seen other questions where it is like this one: http://superuser.com/questions/787486/vim-marks-and-us-international-keyboard